# validate sitemap document

Tags: xml, xsd, sitemap, xml-validation

I'm trying to validate [this sitemap file](http://summer-festivals.cloudfoundry.com/home/sitemap). When I validate it inside my IDE I get the error:

```
External resource http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 is not registered
```

I've also validated it using [an online validator](http://www.xmlvalidation.com), which generates a multitude of errors. I've looked through the document, and can't see anything wrong it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two issues with your sitemap.

**First** - The value of `<lastmod>` is invalid. In your time value, the schema is expecting the seconds. Also, the timezone designator is missing a colon.

Example -

This: `<lastmod>2012-02-08T16:32+0000</lastmod>`

Should be: `<lastmod>2012-02-08T16:32:00+00:00</lastmod>`

---

**Second** -  The position of `<lastmod>` is incorrect. According to the schema, the order has to be: `<loc>`, `<lastmod>`, `<changefreq>`, and then `<priority>`.

Example -

This:

```
  <url>
    <loc>http://summer-festivals.cloudfoundry.com/festival/show/7</loc>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>0.7</priority>
    <lastmod>2012-02-08T16:32:00+00:00</lastmod>
  </url>
```

Should be:

```
  <url>
    <loc>http://summer-festivals.cloudfoundry.com/festival/show/7</loc>
    <lastmod>2012-02-08T16:32:00+00:00</lastmod>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>0.7</priority>
  </url>
```

---

Here is a full copy of the fixed sitemap.xml:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
  <url>
    <loc>http://summer-festivals.cloudfoundry.com/</loc>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>1.0</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://summer-festivals.cloudfoundry.com/privacy</loc>
    <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    <priority>0.1</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://summer-festivals.cloudfoundry.com/terms</loc>
    <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    <priority>0.1</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://summer-festivals.cloudfoundry.com/about</loc>
    <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    <priority>0.8</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://summer-festivals.cloudfoundry.com/artist/show/1</loc>
    <lastmod>2012-02-08T16:32:00+00:00</lastmod>
    <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    <priority>0.5</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://summer-festivals.cloudfoundry.com/artist/show/2</loc>
    <lastmod>2012-02-08T16:32:00+00:00</lastmod>
    <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    <priority>0.5</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://summer-festivals.cloudfoundry.com/festival/show/1</loc>
    <lastmod>2012-02-08T16:32:00+00:00</lastmod>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>0.7</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://summer-festivals.cloudfoundry.com/festival/show/2</loc>
    <lastmod>2012-02-08T16:32:00+00:00</lastmod>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>0.7</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://summer-festivals.cloudfoundry.com/festival/show/3</loc>
    <lastmod>2012-02-08T16:32:00+00:00</lastmod>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>0.7</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://summer-festivals.cloudfoundry.com/festival/show/4</loc>
    <lastmod>2012-02-08T16:32:00+00:00</lastmod>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>0.7</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://summer-festivals.cloudfoundry.com/festival/show/5</loc>
    <lastmod>2012-02-08T16:32:00+00:00</lastmod>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>0.7</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://summer-festivals.cloudfoundry.com/festival/show/7</loc>
    <lastmod>2012-02-08T16:32:00+00:00</lastmod>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>0.7</priority>
  </url>
</urlset>
```